# How to distinguish between Clojure-JVM and Clojure-CLR

Tags: clojure

How can I detect within a clojure-lang script file whether the script is run on JVM version or CLR version?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

The tool to use here, are reader conditions:  https://clojure.org/guides/reader_conditionals

> ... Reader conditionals are integrated into the Clojure reader, and don’t require
>   any extra tooling beyond Clojure 1.7 or greater. To use reader conditionals,
>   all you need is for your file to have a `.cljc` extension and to use Clojure
>   1.7 or ClojureScript 0.0-3196 or higher ...
>
> ... The standard reader conditional behaves similarly to a traditional
>   `cond`. The syntax for usage is `#?` and looks like:
>
> ```clj
> #?(:clj  (Clojure expression)
>    :cljs (ClojureScript expression)
>    :cljr (Clojure CLR expression)
>    :default (fallthrough expression))
> ```